# Replacing fragments in SingleTask activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Activity A is a SingleTask activity. In its OnCreate callback I create and attach a fragment to the layout.

Activity B is now launched and A is paused and its OnSaveInstanceState is called.

Activity A is now re-invoked with a new intent (because of an interaction in B). In OnNewIntent() I create a new fragment based on the new intent and replace the previous fragment.

This leads to an IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this action after onSaveInstanceState.

What is the right way of doing this? It looks like the framework still considers A to be paused even though OnNewIntent() has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `super.onNewIntent(intent)` to update the FragmentManager's state such that you can do FragmentTransactions.